# Draping data onto an elevation map

Tags: algorithms, graphics

I'm looking for a computational method for projecting data from one grid onto another dissimilar grid while preserving the area of the original grid. I'm not quite sure what these methods would be called, but think draping a blanket over an uneven surface, a bit like what's being done [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/draping-data-on-elevation-maps.html), except my original data set's grid extents will be smaller than the terrain data set's grid extents. I don't care about the fancy graphics portion of it, I'd just like to project my original (2D flat) data set onto the topologically varying data set.

My apologies if I'm being unclear or if I'm asking an obvious/simple question. Thanks!